# Restricting a node to a group of values in a XML Schema

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I'm dealing with xml files where there are many nodes with "auxiliary data" which has the structure:

```
<something>
  <ID>...</ID>
  <Description>...</Description>
</something>
```

For each "something" only some groups of values are valid.

For instance, if one of these "somethings" is `<sex>`, only the following two values would be valid:

```
<sex>
  <ID>00</ID>
  <Description>male</Description>
<sex>

<sex>
  <ID>01</ID>
  <Description>female</Description>
<sex>
```

If it were `<state>` only the following three values would be ok:

```
<state>
  <ID>100</ID>
  <Description>downloaded</Description>
</state>

<state>
  <ID>110</ID>
  <Description>printed</Description>
</state>

<state>
  <ID>120</ID>
  <Description>erased</Description>
</state>
```

I'd like to use XML schema validation to reject files with invalid values but everything I've tried has failed: setting up a root `<aux_dataType>` and restricting the values in the inherited `<sexType>` or `<stateType>`, using groups, etc.

Can you think of a way to address this issue other than validating at the app level?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constraints on ID and Description depend on the parent elements.  You can make their declarations depend in the same way, by using element declarations for `ID` and `Description` local to their parent:

```
<xs:element name="state">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ID" type="state-ID"/>
      <xs:element name="Description" type="state-desc"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="sex">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element name="ID" type="sex-ID"/>
      <xs:element name="Description" type="sex-desc"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:simpleType name="state-ID">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
    <xs:enumeration value="100"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="110"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="120"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="state-desc">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
    <xs:enumeration value="downloaded"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="printed"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="erased"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="sexID">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
    <xs:enumeration value="00"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="01"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="sex-desc">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:NMTOKEN">
    <xs:enumeration value="male"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="female"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Note that this doesn't address consistency requirements:  if I understand your design, the `Description` element is entirely redundant and all the information is conveyed by `ID` -- or vice versa.  In real life, I'd design the XML more simply:  `<sex>male</sex>` and `<state>erased</state>`, or (since these look to be properties of other objects) more likely as attributes:  ... `sex="male"`, ... `state="erased"`.  (And if you want to use coded values for the sex of human beings, you should probably look at ISO 5218.)

Comment: Constraining the range of values for each element is the easy part. It's making 00/male and 01/female valid, but 00/female and 01/male invalid the hard part. Of course, as you note, the design is redundant but it's a given and I have to work with it as it is; I can't influence it.

For the sake of it, I haven't read ISO5218, but my `sex` element doesn't concern humans. Oh, and there's actually more than two values in my files for that element. I simplified it to avoid that "noise" in my question. :-)

Comment: Sorry to have answered the wrong question; I answered the question you appeared to be asking.  Now that you've been clearer, I can advise you to look on the Web for co-occurrence constraints in XSD; there are plenty of Stack Overflow questions which provide the information you need.

Comment: C.M. you've been of great help. All I needed was the term to use in my search of info, and you gave it to me: "co-occurrence constraints". I'd never have found it by myself.